# Ncurses wmove pad

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm doing a text editor in C and ncurses. Everything (or almost) works as intended, except a strange thing that I can only describe with a gif: (the footer describes the buffer after the cursor and the header various buffer info and the x/y used for wmove())

[image: Problem image]

The main loop display section is basically:

```
wmove(pad, winrow + y, wincol + x);
prefresh(pad, winrow, wincol, 1, 0, LINES - 2, COLS - 1);
```

In the example, both winrow and wincol are 0, so I don't understand the cursor jump that always occurs at this point (even if resizing the window and testing different lines).

Sorry if the description is scarce, I can provide information if needed, but I can't post all the code (big!) here.

Comment: Not enough information there. Is there a tab anywhere on that line, and are you processing these correctly?

Comment: Yes there is and the tab indeed increases the x with TABSIZE. There's isn't anything obvious that could explain this. I kind of "resolved" the problem by doing this: http://a.pomf.se/dtafoa.gif